# MissingMethodException when passing an implementing class instead of an interface

Tags: inheritance, groovy, jira, signature

I'm developing a script on Jira workflows (using Adaptavist Scriptrunner v.6.34) and I'm facing an issue in which groovy does not accept an interface implementation as a parameter to a function whose signature allows the implemented interface.

**Code**

```java
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.DefaultRemoteIssueLinkManager;

(...)

def remoteLink = DefaultRemoteIssueLinkManager.getRemoteIssueLinksForIssue(issue)
```

(`issue` is a build variable of type `com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueImpl`)

**What happens**

```java
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.DefaultRemoteIssueLinkManager.getRemoteIssueLinksForIssue() is applicable for argument types: (com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueImpl) values: [ADA-24684]
Possible solutions: getRemoteIssueLinksForIssue(com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue)
    at Script6.run(Script6.groovy:32)
```

- The method documentation is [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.19.0/com/atlassian/jira/issue/link/DefaultRemoteIssueLinkManager.html#getRemoteIssueLinksForIssue-com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue-)
- The method signature expects a parameter of type [Issue](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.19.0/com/atlassian/jira/issue/Issue.html) (an Interface)
- The parameter I am passing is of type [IssueImpl](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.19.0/com/atlassian/jira/issue/IssueImpl.html)

I don't understand how groovy does not accept an interface implementation.

**What I tried so far**

- Conversion of my variable to type `Issue`
- Casting my variable to type `Issue`
- Conversion of my variable to type `MutableIssue` ([the first-level inherited interface](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.19.0/com/atlassian/jira/issue/MutableIssue.html))
- Casting my variable to type `MutableIssue`
- Conversion of my variable to type `AbstractIssue` ([the first-level inherited class](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.19.0/com/atlassian/jira/issue/AbstractIssue.html))
- Casting my variable to type `AbstractIssue`

All those situations returned the original exception.

I've printed the methods and interfaces of the classes and everything matches the documentation, so no version mismatch here.

I don't know what else to do as it is going beyond my java/groovy knowledge. I've asked to colleagues which are java experts and they are not finding a reason for this behaviour. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DefaultRemoteIssueLinkManager.getRemoteIssueLinksForIssue(issue)
```

That is attempting to invoke a static method named `getRemoteIssueLinksForIssue` on the `DefaultRemoteIssueLinkManager` class.  There does not appear to be any such method, and the error you are seeing is consistent with that.

The method you linked at [docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.19.0/com/atlassian/jira/issue/link/DefaultRemoteIssueLinkManager.html#getRemoteIssueLinksForIssue-com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue-](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.19.0/com/atlassian/jira/issue/link/DefaultRemoteIssueLinkManager.html#getRemoteIssueLinksForIssue-com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue-) is an instance method, not a static method.

Comment: "I've asked to colleagues which are java experts and they are not finding a reason for this behaviour."   Ask them if the static method description above makes sense to them.  If they are Java experts I expect it will.

Comment: ok, and can you show me where is that explicit on the docs? Or, at least, where is the documentation for the static method?

Comment: "ok, and can you show me where is that explicit on the docs?" - Sort of.  The default javadoc template doesn't generate any markers to say that a member is *not* static so the absence of that in the javadoc is the standard way to express that something is an instance method.  As an example, https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.19.0/com/atlassian/jira/issue/link/DefaultRemoteIssueLinkManager.html#MAX_GLOBAL_ID_LIST_SIZE_FOR_FIND indicates that this member is `static`.

Comment: "Or, at least, where is the documentation for the static method?" - As far as I know, there is no static method with that name on that class and if I am right about that, then there isn't any documentation for that static method.

Comment: If you run something simple like `String.substring(4)` you will see a very similar error message.  The problem is you are invoking a static method that doesn't exist, but happens to have the same name as an instance method.

Comment: "The problem is you are invoking a static method that doesn't exist, but happens to have the same name as an instance method" - How does it have a name if it doesn't exist?

Comment: So, I'm invoking a method that does not exist but the exception returned is that I am passing wrong parameters, is that it? (Thank you btw!)

Comment: "So, I'm invoking a method that does not exist but the exception returned is that I am passing wrong parameters, is that it?" - The first part is definitely true.  The second part is kind of true.  The part of the error message that tells you that the method does not exist is "No signature of method: static com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.DefaultRemoteIssueLinkManager.getRemoteIssueLinksForIssue() is applicable for argument types: (com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueImpl)".  The "Possible solutions..." part can be confusing, but basically you are correct.

Comment: "How does it have a name if it doesn't exist?" - The method you are invoking has a name because you typed the method name "getRemoteIssueLinksForIssue" into your source code.  The method doesn't because the folks who wrote the `DefaultRemoteIssueLinkManager` class didn't write a static method with that name.